# How to change bower's default cache folder?

Tags: bower, package-managers

On *nix, bower uses the `~/.bower` folder for its cache (packages and so on).
I would like to change this to a different location.

The bower [spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#heading=h.4pzytc1f9j8k) document from suggests that I configure the `storage` key in my `.bowerrc`.

I have created one in my project folder like so:

```
{
  "storage": {
     "cache": "~/blah/cached",
     "git": "~/blah/git_templates"
  }
}
```

When running `bower install - i` see that it still tries to save into `~/.bower`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ? And/or if there is a different way to change the location ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem, after some tries according the spec, I gave up...

So I reviewed `bower`'s history on github and found:

- Before `v0.10.0`, bower used ***config.cache*** (`lib/core/ResolveCache.js`) for its cache location
- After that, satazor rewrote bower's core, now using ***config.storage.cache*** at the beginning, i bet the [spec doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1APq7oA9tNao1UYWyOm8dKqlRP2blVkROYLZ2fLIjtWc/edit#) was written at this time. From the spec:

> storage [object]
>
> Where to store persistent data, such as cache, needed by bower. Defaults to paths that > suite the OS/platform. Valid keys are `cache`, `registry`, `links`, `completion`.

- However, after [this](https://github.com/bower/bower/commit/4d8dbefc851a1283ecede7114a9ed0548376cba5) commit, satazor now uses ***config.storage.packages*** *instead* of config.storage.cache
- After that, in the `v1.0.0` release, the `config` is always set to config.storage.packages, **but the spec has not reflected this change ever since**

### Solution

- Export the environment variable `bower_storage__packages`
- Use a `.bowerrc` such as:

  ```
  {
    "storage":{
        "packages":"/path/to/cache"
    }
  }
  ```

P.S.: I think that linking the spec doc in Google Docs isn't a good idea, maybe github would be a more sensible choice (since we can issue pull requests).

Comment: thanks @knightli  
this is a dead problem to me now, and i can't verify it easily either. but i'm marking this as correct  
P.S: i remember not being able to find the document on github, so i had linked from google docs.

Comment: What does `bower_storage__packages` need to be set to?

Answer (score 4):

What version of bower are you using? Bower 1.0.0 no longer uses ~/.bower. It follows the XDG spec, http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

The "storage" property is only valid for 1.0.0.

Comment: i am on bower 1.0.0

why then, does "bower install" throw an error when i have an improperly formatted .bowerrc ?