# My build server lives behind a very strict firewall, so can I store my Bower dependencies inside the project?

Tags: javascript, bower

I work in a high-security corporate environment.

I'm not allowed to access Bower's index or GitHub from any of the build servers. I can access both of these things from my workstation (for now).

Is there a way to manage all of my project's dependencies some other way - e.g. on an internal index or possibly just dumping the project's dependencies into a directory of the project's source code. Clearly none of these things are as nice as just connecting to the Internet - but I need to be able to do a "bower install" without actual access to the Internet at build-time.

Previously we solved access to Python modules PyPi simply by constructing a static web-site whose content was structured like the PyPi "simple" format. I was hoping that we might be able to do something similar for Bower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

a) set a bower cache folder of your preference and dump all the packages you need to have there ([How to change bower's default cache folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881116/how-to-change-bowers-default-cache-folder))

b) simply commit the project's bower packages folder into your source control

c) use a local git server to host the packages and install from there

Answer (score 1):

Set up a git repository within your organization, with the bower modules you need, and then do:

```
bower install '<git-url>#<git-commit-sha>'
```

Or also any web service will be fine, see http://bower.io/docs/api/#install